# ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts Module not found

Tags: angular2-routing, router, angular2-modules

I'm working on angular-cli. I got following errors.

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/router/src/router_module' in 
'E:\xampp\Angular-cli\Login\src\app'
@ ./src/app/app.module.ts 13:0-69
@ ./src/main.ts
@ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts
```

I've this library **@angular/router/src/router_module** in my **node_module.** What is missing?

Here are required files.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AdminAccount } from './admin/admin.component';
import { LoginForm } from './login/login.component';
import { FileData } from './filedata/filedata.component';
import { ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from "@angular/router/src/router_module";
import { RouterModule, Routes, ROUTES } from "@angular/router";
import { Http, Response } from "@angular/http";
import { Route } from './router/router.component';

@NgModule(
{
imports: [RouterModule ,Route, BrowserModule, Http, Response, AdminAccount, LoginForm, FileData, Route],
declarations: [AppComponent],
providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**router.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { LoginForm } from "../login/login.component";
import { AdminAccount } from "../admin/admin.component";

 export const Route = RouterModule.forRoot(
[
{ path: '/', component: LoginForm },
{ path: '/admin', component: AdminAccount }
]);
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { LoginForm } from "./login/login.component";
import { AdminAccount } from "./admin/admin.component";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { FileData } from "./filedata/filedata.component";

@Component(
{
selector: "root",
templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

If need more file let me know.

Comment: which version of angular are you using?

Comment: @FahadNisar **angular1.** Can you guess, what's the problem? Or you need extra info??

Comment: You have mentioned that you are using angular-cli which required angular 2 or higher. How can you say that you are using angular 1?

Comment: Yeah, You're right. Can you solve my problem now??

Comment: try removing import { ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from "@angular/router/src/router_module"; and providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS], from app.module.ts

Comment: **ERROR in AdminAccount is not an NgModule,** Now what's this??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@Fahad Nasir Here's **AdminAcount.**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Component(
{
selector: "admin",
templateUrl: "./admin.component.html",
})

export class AdminAccount
{
adminUser = document.cookie.split("??")[0];
adminPass = document.cookie.split("??")[1];

constructor(public router: Router)
{
    if (document.cookie !== undefined)
    {
        if (this.adminUser == "admin" && this.adminPass == "admin")
        {
            console.log("Welcome!");
        }
        else
        {
            this.router.navigate(["Loginform"]);
            console.log("Redirect!");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Error: Undefined Login!");
    }
}
}
```

[Here Have a look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74meQ.png)

Comment: ERROR in AdminAccount is not an NgModule

Comment: Well I changed the order of @ngModule imports. Error gone away.
But now there's compilation errors.

Comment: paste the screenshot cant tell you without looking at it.